# Quantative comparison

Tags: combinations

[image]

Any tips for this question, that which quantity will be greater?

Comment: The phrasing is a bit weird, but I would think is option A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quantity A: There are $r \times s \times t$ possible (distinct) combinations of one entree, one side, and one dessert.

Compare that to quantity $B$.

Comment: Lots of green today! +1